# PicklingError caused by p4a.calendar.interfaces.ICalendarSupport when migrating from 3.3.5 to 4.0.7

Tags: upgrade, plone, pickle, zope3

I am trying to migrate a Plone 3.3.5 installation to 4.0.7.

Before migrating, it was decided that Plone4Artists Calendar should be removed.

We followed the procedures proposed here http://plone.org/documentation/kb/cleaning-p4a, applying it for the following interfaces:

```
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import ICalendarEnhanced
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import IPossibleCalendar
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import ICalendarConfig
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import IEventProvider
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import IEvent
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import IBasicCalendarSupport
from p4a.calendar.interfaces import ICalendarSupport
```

Apparently, it works (except for the IPossibleCalendar interface, for which I get a "Can only remove directly provided interfaces." message). In order to remove that, we uninstalled the product (following good advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575770/getting-rid-of-plone4artists-calendar-migration-from-plone-3-3-5-to-plone-4-0-7))

Now, after moving the Data.fs from 3.3.5 to the 4.0.7 install, and trying to activate the migration at /Plone/@@plone-upgrade, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\plone-4.0.7-py2.6.egg\Products\CMFPlone\MigrationTool.py", line 175, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\products.genericsetup-1.6.3-py2.6.egg\Products\GenericSetup\upgrade.py", line 142, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\plone.app.upgrade-1.0.7-py2.6.egg\plone\app\upgrade\v40\alphas.py", line 443, in migrateFolders
    transaction.savepoint(optimistic=True)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\transaction-1.0.1-py2.6.egg\transaction\_manager.py", line 99, in savepoint
    return self.get().savepoint(optimistic)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\transaction-1.0.1-py2.6.egg\transaction\_transaction.py", line 253, in savepoint
    self._saveAndRaiseCommitishError() # reraises!
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\transaction-1.0.1-py2.6.egg\transaction\_transaction.py", line 250, in savepoint
    savepoint = Savepoint(self, optimistic, *self._resources)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\transaction-1.0.1-py2.6.egg\transaction\_transaction.py", line 647, in __init__
    savepoint = savepoint()
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\zodb3-3.9.5-py2.6-win32.egg\ZODB\Connection.py", line 1128, in savepoint
    self._commit(None)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\zodb3-3.9.5-py2.6-win32.egg\ZODB\Connection.py", line 606, in _commit
    self._store_objects(ObjectWriter(obj), transaction)
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\zodb3-3.9.5-py2.6-win32.egg\ZODB\Connection.py", line 640, in _store_objects
    p = writer.serialize(obj)  # This calls __getstate__ of obj
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\zodb3-3.9.5-py2.6-win32.egg\ZODB\serialize.py", line 422, in serialize
    return self._dump(meta, obj.__getstate__())
  File "d:\plone-4.0.7-teste-20110927\buildout-cache\eggs\zodb3-3.9.5-py2.6-win32.egg\ZODB\serialize.py", line 431, in _dump
    self._p.dump(state)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'p4a.calendar.interfaces.ICalendarSupport'>: import of module p4a.calendar.interfaces failed
```

Please note that this is a test run: it is a bogus and clean Data.fs, and the only product involved is P4A.Calendar, which was installed (and uninstalled before moving the Data.fs to the 4.0.7 install) only at the 3.3.5 buildout.

I also tried to follow the advice from [here](http://davidjb.com/blog/2010/06/plone-sitemanager-leftovers-not-the-good-kind), and the SiteManager for the Plone object does not have any adapter or subscriber with the "p4a" string. The **dict** attribute from the global SiteManager does not report any occurrence of the "p4a" string either.

Can anyone give me a light on this? Where should I look for "p4a.calendar.interfaces.ICalendarSupport" in the Data.fs?

Comment: Have you tried http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wildcard.fixpersistentutilities

Comment: If you use fixperistentutilities, there is an option that will go through and remove an interface for you.